# Rspec match array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, rspec

I have an array of hashes, which for the sake of argument looks like this:

```
[{"foo"=>"1", "bar"=>"1"}, {"foo"=>"2", "bar"=>"2"}]
```

Using Rspec, I want to test if `"foo" => "2"` exists in the array, but I don't care whether it's the first or second item. I've tried:

```
[{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}].should include("foo" => "2"))
```

But this doesn't work, as the hashes should match exactly. Is there any way to partially test each hash's content?

Comment: `[{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}].flat_map(&:to_a).should include(["foo","2"])` will work also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `any?` method. See [this](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) for the documentation.

```
hashes = [{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}]
expect(hashes.any? { |hash| hash['foo'] == '2' }).to be_true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you save my day

Comment: fwiw i used `.to be_truthy` Thank you for the clean solution.

Answer (score 49):

how about?

```
hashes = [{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}]
expect(hashes).to include(include('foo' => '2'))
```

Comment: And if you want all instead of any, well, you can use `all`:
    expect(hashes).to all(include('foo' => '2'))

Comment: docs for `all` here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/all-matcher

Comment: This works, but I would phrase it as: `expect(hashes).to include(a_hash_including("foo" => "2"))`

Answer (score 19):

Use [Composable Matchers](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/)

```
hashes = [{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}]
expect(hashes)
  .to match([
    a_hash_including('foo' => '2'), 
    a_hash_including('foo' => '1')
  ])
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use composable matchers

http://rspec.info/blog/2014/01/new-in-rspec-3-composable-matchers/

but I prefer to define a custom matcher like this

```
require 'rspec/expectations'

RSpec::Matchers.define :include_hash_matching do |expected|
  match do |array_of_hashes|
    array_of_hashes.any? { |element| element.slice(*expected.keys) == expected }
  end
end
```

and use it in the specs like this

```
describe RSpec::Matchers do
  describe '#include_hash_matching' do
    subject(:array_of_hashes) do
      [
        {
          'foo' => '1',
          'bar' => '2'
        }, {
          'foo' => '2',
          'bar' => '2'
        }
      ]
    end

    it { is_expected.to include_hash_matching('foo' => '1') }

    it { is_expected.to include_hash_matching('foo' => '2') }

    it { is_expected.to include_hash_matching('bar' => '2') }

    it { is_expected.not_to include_hash_matching('bar' => '1') }

    it { is_expected.to include_hash_matching('foo' => '1', 'bar' => '2') }

    it { is_expected.not_to include_hash_matching('foo' => '1', 'bar' => '1') }

    it 'ignores the order of the keys' do
      is_expected.to include_hash_matching('bar' => '2', 'foo' => '1')
    end
  end
end


Finished in 0.05894 seconds
7 examples, 0 failures
```

Comment: If you want to make it work with a hash that uses symbols, you can do this:

   RSpec::Matchers.define :include_hash_matching do |expected|
     match do |array_of_hashes|
       array_of_hashes.any? do |element|
         expected = expected.stringify_keys
         element = element.stringify_keys
         element.slice(*expected.keys) == expected
       end
     end
   end

Answer (score 0):

If separate testing of hashes is not a strict requirement I would do it this way:

```
[{"foo" => "1", "bar" => "2"}, {"foo" => "2", "bar" => "2"}].map{ |d| d["foo"] }.should include("2")
```